# Отследить изменение элемента в dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

На странице в блок #ya-dir грузится асинхронно блоки с рекламой яндекс директ, как отследить тот момент когда она уже загрузилась?
Мне нужно после загрузки узнать высоту блока

[Вот ссылка на сайт с этой рекламой](http://fotomtv.ru/stati/)

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить только такой способ — http://jsfiddle.net/FpRtB/1/

```
function domObserver(el, callback){
    var done = function (){ callback(el); };
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

    if( MutationObserver ){
        var observer = new MutationObserver(done);
        observer.observe(el, { childList: true });
    }
    else if( el.addEventListener ){
        el.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', done, false); 
    }
    else {
        var html = el.innerHTML;
        setInterval(function (){
            if( html != el.innerHTML ){
                html = el.innerHTML;
                done();
            }
        }, 300);
    }
};

domObserver(document.getElementById('ya-dir'), function (el){
    alert(el.id+' — chnaged');
});
```

Comment: А как выключить этот domObserver?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ya-dir').load(function(){
//Ваша функция для проверки высоты
})
```

Не пойдет?

Comment: Пробывал не проходит, получается что сам элемент то существует, а вот всё что вложено в него нет, пробовал так $('#ya-dir').children() тоже не работает